# Подобрать регулярное выражение для замены строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

помогите пожалуйста подобрать регулярное выражение для замены

```
$s = "#000000{Привет}";
```

на

```
$s = "<a style='color:#000000'>Привет</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$s = "#000000{Привет}";

echo preg_replace('/(\#.*?)\{(.*?)\}/', '<a style="color:$1">$2</a>', $s);
```

Comment: А почему от 1 до 9 цифр?

Comment: @Qwertiy, поспешишь — людей насмешишь, вообще подумал там могут быть и буквы, так как это RGB цвета, исправляюсь)

Comment: `[0-9a-fA-F]{3}|[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|[0-9a-fA-F]{6}|[0-9a-fA-F]{8}` - ну по идее так?

Comment: Хотя можно упростить: `#(?=[0-9a-FA-F]*\{)(\w{3,4}|\w{6}|\w{8})\{`